# What is the "interface" keyword in MSVC?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi, com

I'm looking through the Windows 8.1 SDK and in UnknownBase.h I'm seeing things like

```
typedef interface IUnknown IUnknown;
```

I've never seen this `interface` keyword before. Note that this is very definitely a `.h` header, processed by `cl.exe`. It's not IDL file, and it's not processed by `midl.exe`.

I found this online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50h7kwtb.aspx

But `__interface` is not the same as `interface`

Can anyone clue me in here?

Comment: Is there a `#define interface` somewhere? It's sure not natively a C++ keyword, but the preprocessor could make it look like one.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just right-click "interface" in the editor and select Go To Definition.  __interface is a non-standard keyword, [well documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50h7kwtb.aspx).  As you can tell, it provides a lot more guarantees than *struct* does.  The concept is pretty big in many languages, massive in COM.  It can be expressed in C++ as well without language extensions, just a lot more error prone.  A compiler can tell you when you made a mistake, but only if it understands the concept.

Comment: @HansPassant Oddly, when I right clicked on `interface` in visual studio the option for `Go To Definition` was grayed out (which is what prompted my stack overflow post in the first place). But as I describe in a comment below to MarcoA, a findstr did the trick. It's odd that that visual studio can't find it though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Microsoft has some compiler-specific extensions like the one you linked but `interface` shouldn't be a native C++ compiler-specific keyword but rather a define which substitutes something (in BaseTyps.h it used to be defined as follows)

```
# define interface  struct
```

[Link here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/bin/MinGW/include/basetyps.h)

If you want to verify this do a [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for such a definition and you should find something similar.

---

References: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/06bf1dea-1d20-4ec3-b9a1-3d673d7fcd8d/what-is-the-interface-keyword-in-native-c

Comment: Wow, yep, that's it. I did a `findstr /s /i /c:"#define interface" *` from within `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include`, and in `combaseapi.h` I found `#define interface struct`